# Data doesn't get submitted to database from Django forms using classed based views

Tags: django, forms, django-class-based-views

I'm am trying to make a registration page for Companies and the whole flow is working fine using froms in Django. Though when I fill out the form with data and hit submit it redirects me to my index page and doesn't show any error. But when I check the database in /admin the object/data is not submitted. Any idea what the "error" could be?

I'm using class based views and I've added my model in admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Company)
```

My urls.py path looks like this:

```
path('createCompanyProfile/', CompanyFormView.as_view(), name = "createCompanyProfile"),
```

---

**models.py:**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    companyName = models.CharField(max_length = 145)
    description = models.TextField()
    websiteURL = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    relationToDjango = models.TextField()
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length = 11)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    mainContact = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    streetName = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    houseNumber = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    postalCode = models.CharField(max_length = 4)
    region = models.CharField(max_length = 45)    

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(self.companyName, self.description, self.websiteURL, self.relationToDjango, self.phoneNumber, self.email, self.mainContact, self.streetName, self.houseNumber, self.postalCode, self.region)


class CompanyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

**views.py:**

```
class CompanyFormView(FormView):
    model = Company
    template_name = "company/createCompanyProfile.html"
    form_class = CompanyForm
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(CompanyFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

---

**createCompanyProfile.html**

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Create Profile">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `FormView` which does nothing when a submitted form is valid, since it is designed with the thought that you will write the code for what is to be done in case the form is valid (which you haven't). Since you want to create an object with this view it is better for you to use a [`CreateView` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview):

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView


class CompanyFormView(CreateView):
    model = Company
    template_name = "company/createCompanyProfile.html"
    form_class = CompanyForm
    success_url = '/'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in views.py file. You are using FormView. Use CreateView data will be save to DB.

```
# import
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

#yor class
class CompanyFormView(CreateView):

     model = Company
     template_name = "company/createCompanyProfile.html"
     form_class = CompanyForm
     success_url = '/'
```